# WPF Generics:How to define a list of objects as parameter of a function

Tags: wpf, generics

I want create a generic (general) method which accepts the return types of LINQ 2 SQL query (a list of objects- IEnumerable) against different table as the parameter of the function. How can I define my parameter for the function ? I will use this function to bind the data to a grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer here

```
Public Sub FormatGrid(Of T)(ByVal varList As IEnumerable(Of T))

End Sub
```